# Is yuidoc @namespace relevant with Ember-CLI?

Tags: ember-cli, yuidoc

@namespace

> The @namespace should not include the "root" or "global" object that
>   your entire library hangs off of.

Since we have @module which give the js files container.
can some one give me a simplest example possible? or direct me to some link

Comment: `@namespace` is useful to group your modules, as in `@namespace Routes` which lets you differentiate between `potato/index.js` and `otherPotato/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

@namespace is not useful if we are using ES6 
instead modules and sub-modules should be used.